# coTurn server behind NAT

Tags: webrtc, stun, turn, coturn

I am using coTurn as my turn server in my application.
what is the minimum configuration to do to make my Turn server work behind NAT?
what are all ports I have to open for it to work behind NAT?
As I have read coturn comes with inbuilt STUN so can I use STUN address in my application instead of default google STUN mentioned here https://github.com/coturn/coturn/wiki/CoturnConfig
if so what should be my configuration there to be modified in the javascript object in RTCPeerConnection

Comment: Have you found a solution yet?

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming `work behind NAT` refers to the TURN server, and not to the application.

In this case, you can refer to the [external-ip](https://github.com/coturn/coturn/blob/master/README.turnserver#L374) parameter in `coturn` configuration:

> TURN Server public/private address mapping, if the server is behind NAT. In that situation, if a -X is used in form "-X " then that ip will be reported as relay IP address of all allocations.

This works for example in NAT scenarios like AWS of GCP, where there's a 1:1 mapping between a private IP address, where `coturn` can listen on, and an ephemeral public IP address.

Your application can just be configured to use `coturn` in the `ice` settings as if `coturn` was listening directly on the public IP.

e.g.:

```
listening-ip=172.10.1.1

external-ip=3.3.3.3/172.10.1.1
```

Furthermore, `coturn` will respond to Allocate requests with relay transport addresses with the public IP in the `XOR-RELAYED-ADDRESS` of the Allocate Success response.

The port will be the same as the one allocated on the private interface. So for example if the relay is allocated on `172.10.1.1:40032`, the `XOR-RELAYED-ADDRESS` will contain `3.3.3.3:40032`.

Needless to say, whatever port range is configured in `coturn`'s configuration needs to be reachable from the applications. For example if `min-port` is 40000 and `max-port` is 50000, there must be a Security Group for that EC2 instance which allows accessing to UDP 40000-50000.

By default `coturn` acts also as a STUN server (even fully RFC-5780 compatible if listening on more than one IP address).